# Running a Batch File from Task Scheduler Without User being logged In

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I'm trying to run a batch file on Windows 7 from the Task Scheduler.  I can run the batch file fine if I run it from the command prompt.

If I run it from the Task Scheduler to only run when the user is logged in, the task will run without any issues. However, when it runs when the user is not logged in, the Task Scheduler looks like it's running the file but nothing happens.

I've tried changing the batch file to nothing but the following line to ensure it's not because of what's in the batch file:

```
echo "success" >> c:\temp\test.log
```

and that does not work.  Any ideas?  I have it being run with the highest privileges and with an admin account that has full permissions to the batch file and the folder where the file is being written.

Comment: What account are you using to run the task? What triggers did you set?

Comment: Try running the task as a System Service account.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### TASK SCHEDULER: SCHEDULED BATCH SCRIPT NOT RUNNING

**Task Scheduler Properties. . .**

From Windows `Task Scheduler` on the job <kbd>**`Properties`**</kbd> *(see bottom most screen shots)* in the. . .

- **1.** **<kbd>`General`</kbd>** tab, ensure that the below options are select/checked or unchecked just as shown in **Print Screen A**

  - *Uncheck* `Run only when user is logged on`
  - *Check* `Run whether user is logged on or not`
  - *Check* `Run with the highest privileges`
- **2.** **<kbd>`Conditions`</kbd>** tab, ensure that the below options are **select**, **checked**, or **unchecked** just as shown in **Print Screen B**

  - *Check* `Wake the computer to run this task`
- **3.** **<kbd>`Actions`</kbd>** tab, click **<kbd>`Edit`</kbd>**, and ensure that the `Start in (optional)` is set just as shown in the below example (**DO NOT** put double quote marks around it) for the full path pointing where the batch script is located **WITHOUT** a final backslash "`\`" **Print Screen C**

---

### **SECURITY CONSIDERATIONS**

- *Once you press **<kbd>`OK`</kbd>** (**2.** above) it should prompt you for the credential to run this as, and that credential is what will need access to **`EXECUTE`** the batch file where it exist, and it will also need access to do whatever the batch file is running that you scripted out.*
- *It may be best to setup a static service/proxy user account for this process and then use its credentials to run the process. You'd need to ensure its password is strong and it set to never expire—and it needs access to **`EXECUTE`** the batch and run whatever the batch scripted process is running and any commands and resources, ect. it utilizes as well.*
- It seems the option `Run whether user is logged on or not` you MUST
  check the option `Run with highest privileges` for it to actually
  run as expected from the Task Scheduler.

**Error Checking**

- If there is an issue with the actual batch script but the Windows **Task
  Scheduler** actually does execute it to run it but the batch script
  logic errors out, etc. for whatever reason, the **Task Scheduler** may
  not see this failure at this level. From its perspective (by default most of the time), it’s
  executing the batch file so as long as it can execute it and has
  access to do so, its job is done successfully.
- Add **error checking** or **logging** to the batch script logic to **catch** (or **troubleshoot**) issues at this level including ensuring that the security context which the batch scheduler executes it as has appropriate access to commands, resources, etc. which the batch script runs as.

---

### Group Policy Considerations

[**CHECK GROUP POLICY AND LOG ON AS A BATCH JOB PERMISSIONS**](http://www.brooksnet.com/faq/117-02.html)

> **Answer:** *On Windows, this privilege is granted through the **Local** or **Domain Security Policy**. To do this using the **Local Security Policy**,
>   follow these steps.*
>
> 1. In the **Control Panel**, open **Administrative Tools**, then **Local Security**
>      Policy.
> 2. Beneath **Security Settings**, open **Local Policies** and highlight **User
>      Rights Assignment**.
> 3. Locate **Log on as a batch job**. Open the **properties** and add any users
>      that need this right.
> 4. When finished, **save** your changes and close the **Local Security
>      Settings** window.
>
> Your changes should take effect immediately. To make changes to the
>   Domain Security Policy, on a domain controller, use the **Domain
>   Security Policy utility** in the **Control Panel**

---

### Batch Script Logic with Mapped Drives or Full UNC Path, and issues. . .

If your script is referencing a mapped network drive but you want it to `Run whether the user is logged on or not`, then under this context, the drive mapping may not actually be there for the batch process to do what’s expected.

If possible, use `UNC` paths in your batch script logic rather than a mapped drive letter to avoid issues.  Otherwise, you may need to use `PUSHD \\ServerName\ShareName` at the beginning of the batch process and then use `POPD` at the end of the batch process. You could map the drive with `NET USE X: \\ServerName\ShareName` at the beginning of the batch process and then disconnect the drive with `NET USE X: /DELETE` at the end of the batch process.

- [**NET USE**](http://ss64.com/nt/net_use.html)
- [**PUSHD**](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html)
- [**POPD**](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html)

---

### OTHERS

- [**MS HOTFIX (KB977353): Group Policy Immediate Task preference item does not run on a client computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/977353)
- Look at the scheduled task's <kbd>**`Settings`**</kbd> tab and the option listed as `Stop the task if it runs longer than:`. If this option is check and the time period is less than a script that's running, Task Scheduler will kill it early and thus you may not get the expected results. This is something else to check when troubleshooting just in case.

  [image]
- From the <kbd>**`Triggers`**</kbd> tab of the scheduled task when you select the <kbd>**`Edit`**</kbd> option be sure to set the `Start:` time and date are of a value that's NOT already passed. Be sure that this has the date and time set to that of a value in the *Future*. Otherwise you may notice that the job states that it's scheduled to run at the next scheduled time as you'd expect; however, it doesn't get executed by **Task Scheduler** nor does the **Task Scheduler** `History` tab show that it is ever executed (because it's not). Simply edit the trigger and update it with a future date and/or time to resolve this issue if you're experiencing it.

  [image]

---

**PRINT SCREENS**

**Print Screen A**

[image]

**Print Screen B**

[image]

**Print Screen C**

[image]